# iMessage via WiFi only

Tags: wifi, iphone, messages, preferences

Is there a way to rig iMessage so it receives (and, I guess,sends) messages only when connected via WiFi and not when connected via the carrier's data plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there's no such option / preference. You could, though, turn off your carrier's data plan altogether by turning off the **Cellular Data** option (under **Settings / General/ Cellular** on iOS 6 and **Settings / General / Network** on iOS 5).

Comment: Re your second sentence: Do you mean, under "Settings" / "Messages", to select "Send as SMS": "OFF"?

Comment: @msh210 No. What I suggest will turn off your carrier's data plan. Despite the title, as in your questions you specify the *carrier's data plan* I just stuck to the Wifi - 3G (or whatever) restriction. If, indeed, you want to use it **only** via WiFi, then, yes, the *Send as SMS* should be disabled too.

Comment: +1 on the answer ("No"), but I don't see any "Settings" / "Cellular".

Comment: @msh210 My bad. I'll edit my answer with the correct path.